# Show another Tab Bar Controller From Current Tab Bar Controller

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, segue

I have following View Controller hierarchy in my storyboard. 
[image]
When I perform show segue from tab 1 of Groups Tab bar Controller by selecting the tableview cell, the Lists tab bar is presented but it have Groups's tab bar instead of its own tab bar. 
How can I make it to show it's own tab bar when Lists's Controller is shown. Thanks

PS: I have one more tab bar controller in the hierarchy.

Comment: try navigation controller before second tabbar controller

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you set the Storyboard ID in interface builder for "List Tab Bar Controller." (Example below `tabBar2`)
2. Give a name for the segue between the `TableViewController` and `ListTabBarController`. (Example below `show1`)
3. Add the following code to prepare (for segue):

   ```
   override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
       if segue.identifier == "show1" {
           let _ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
           let storyborad = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
           let tabVC2 = storyborad.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBar2") as! UITabBarController
           self.present(tabVC2, animated: true, completion: nil)
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: I want to push it, not present.

Comment: Just like whatsapp app do on tapping on a chat. It pushes a new view controller from tab bar controller.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this code

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
}
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = false
}
```

in Table View Controller of both Tab bar Controllers worked. Now every Tab bar Controller's View Controllers have their own tab bar.